# как сертификат позволяет обезопасить соединение

Tags: безопасность, https

объясните доходчиво как сертификат обезопасит мое соединение с сайтом, например, где я ввожу пароль. Что значит, что он доверенное лицо, как я это проверяю

Answer (score 8):

Если вы соединяетесь по защищённому соединению (HTTPS, SSL), это означает, что весь трафик между вашей машиной и машиной-назначением (сервером) шифруется и доступен только вам и серверу. Никто более не может расшифровать данные при передаче. Этим обеспечивается безопасность при передаче критичных данных, например, паролей.

В защищённом соединении присутствует понятие сертификата. Сертификат используется для проверки аутентичности сторон. В данном случае, для проверки аутентичности сервера. Он гарантирует, что сервер является тем, за кого он себя выдаёт. Т.е., например, вы соединяетесь с сайтом *example.com* и сертификат гарантирует, что это именно *example.com*, а не фейковый сайт, желающий стырить ваш драгоценный пароль.

Проверка сертификата осуществляется достаточно просто. Сертификат выдаётся для конкретных доменных имён. Если имя, указанное в сертификате, не соответствует доменному имени сайта, вы увидите предупреждение браузера.

Вроде бы, никто не помешает злобному кулхацкеру Васе выпустить свой собственный (т.н. самоподписанный) сертификат для *example.com*, подменить IP-адрес и стырить ваш драгоценный пароль. Чтобы этого не произошло, сертификат подписывается в удостоверяющем центре (центре сертификации, ЦС). ЦС проверяет каким-либо образом, что сертификат выдаётся именно тому человеку/сайту, за который он себя выдаёт. Все сертификаты, подписанные доверенным ЦС, также автоматически считаются доверенными.

В современных операционных системах есть централизованное хранилище сертификатов корневых центров сертификации. Эти сертификаты поставляются вместе с ОС и периодически обновляются при обновлении ОС. Все сертификаты, подписанные корневыми ЦС будут доверенными.

Особняком стоит Firefox, который имеет собственную базу корневых ЦС и игнорирует системную.

Никто не мешает пользователю добавить произвольный сертификат в хранилище доверенных сертификатов и наслаждаться видом зелёненького значка в браузере. Можно пойти ещё дальше и создать свой ЦС, т.е. выпустить собственный корневой сертификат и, добавив его в доверенные, считать также доверенными все подписанные им сертификаты.